# How to use the @PreviewParameter annotation?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to get a preview of a composable which takes one String parameter as input. I am not sure how the `@PreviewParameter` annotation is supposed to be used.

This is was I tried

```
class DogProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<String> {
    override val values = listOf("Bela", "Stalone").asSequence()
}

@PreviewParameter(DogProvider::class)
@Composable
fun OverviewCard(
    dog: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Text(dog)
}
```

No preview is rendered. If I also add the `@Preview` annotation it says that I should use `@PreviewParameter`

Comment: Just a warning: `PreviewParameterProvider` implementation **must** be public, otherwise preview will not display anything. Not even an error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are very close, but the `@PreviewParameter` should be applied your Composable's parameters, not the function itself.

Your example should look like this:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun OverviewCardPreview(
    @PreviewParameter(DogProvider::class) dog: String,
) {
    Text(dog)
}
```

Also note that you can currently only have a single `@PreviewParameter`-annotated property for each previewed composable.

Answer (score 10):

Since the Jetpack-Compose API tells us:

> Multiple @PreviewParameter are not allowed

So the best thing to do to avoid having to initialize parameters by default if we have more than one, is to wrap all the parameters in a data class and mock them in the implementation of `PreviewParameterProvider`

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun FeatureScreenPreviewMock(
    @PreviewParameter(FeatureScreenPreviewParamProvider::class) featureScreenParams: FeatureScreenParams,
)

class FeatureScreenPreviewParamProvider : PreviewParameterProvider<FeatureScreenParams>
```

In this way we are not limited to the number of parameters

---

*Sample with [WelcomeScreenPreviewMock](https://github.com/Coronel-B/Mobius-KMM/commit/b65e083b837326559049760ce14f4e43f2e30e3f#diff-306ba9b19e21a1879eeab873e8e56a23e71f2dcf8167a4d18de3fca3d943074e)*

Comment: The link is no longer working - error 404.

Comment: If you need the full code I could update the answer

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have already found more information about preview providers :)