# Multiple @PreviewParameters not allowed (Jetpack)

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I need to use the @Preview annotation with my @Compostable class, which takes two arguments in its constructor.

So I set up two PreviewParameterProviders and added the @PreviewParameter annotation before each of the arguments.

The second one is flagged with a compile error: "Multiple @PreviewParameter are not allowed".

How does this work? Do I just declare one PreviewProvider that provides both values?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: You can wrap your params in a data class and then, use a single provider class for preview. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67831364/5752443).